# Add class to elements with certain class

Tags: jquery, django, forms, validation, twitter-bootstrap

I'm generating a form with Django, and the validation errors is displayed like this (there can be several):

```
<ul class="errorlist">
    <li>This field is mandatory.</li>
</ul>
```

I want to style the errors the "Twitter Boostrap way", by adding the class(es) "alert alert-error", and thought a way could be with the use of jQuery. This is my (poor) try, that isn't working:

```
$('.errorList').each(function() {
    $(this).addClass('alert alert-error');
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `$('.errorList li').addClass('alert alert-error')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

and use errorlist instead of errorList (lower "l")

```
$('.errorlist').each(function() {
    console.log("!", (this));
    $(this).addClass('alert alert-error');
});
```

Comment: Yep, that was the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `each` function, just call `addClass` like this:

```
$('.errorlist').addClass('alert alert-error');
```

P.S. There doesn't seem to be any good reason to add those css classes via javascript, you should output them right away from your server side code.

Answer (score 0):

No point in using `.each()`.  Just do:

```
$('.errorList').addClass('alert alert-error');
```